# Ajax request loosing path on .load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url, path

I loaded an ajax request to update values in `#mainContent`:

```
  success: function(response) {
    $('#mainContent').load('ct/netlinking/ct_netlinking.php');
```

ct_netlinking.php contains:

```
// Scripts de gestion de la table de netlinking :
include_once('mo/netlinking/mo_netlinking_getThis.php');

// Chargement des données du site actuel :
$netlinkingTable = netlinkingTableGet($_SESSION['selectedWebsiteId']);

// Affichage de la page de netlinking :
include_once('vi/vi_netlinking.php');
```

structure:

```
ct/
  netlinking/
    ct_netlinking.php
mo/
  netlinking/
    mo_netlinking_getThis.php
```

But I get this error:

> Warning: include_once(mo/netlinking/mo_netlinking_getThis.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   E:\www\backoffice\ct\netlinking\ct_netlinking.php on line 6

Line 6 contains:

```
include_once('mo/netlinking/mo_netlinking_getThis.php');
```

Why do I lose the path and how can I find it back?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because it is searching for a page `ct/netlinking/mo/netlinking/mo_netlinking_getThis.php` as your script is within that directory, it will append to the end of the current path/directory your scripts are in.

Try using;

```
include_once(../../mo/netlinking/mo_netlinking_getThis.php);
```

You may also get this for the other include that you have to, so this edit should also fix that too `include_once('../../vi/vi_netlinking.php');`